# Serialize my DateTimeEx type with JavaScriptSerializer to behave the same as DateTime

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have a new DateTimeEx type that has a property of type DateTime. I need to get the JavaScriptSerializer to treat my DateTimeEx type exactly like DateTime when serializing it to get something like **\"\/Date(1431006511857)\/\"** as you would when calling Serialize on a DateTime type.

I've implemented my own JavaScriptConverter that makes use of the CustomString : Uri trick as in [this](http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/04/beg-steal-or-borrow-decent-javascript.html) article.

I do the following to build my new string.

```
 public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) {
            DateTimeEx dateTimeEx = (DateTimeEx)obj;
            DateTime dateTime = dateTimeEx.GetDateTimeComponent();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("\"\\/Date(");
            var dtVal = (dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000L;
            sb.Append(dtVal);
            sb.Append(")\\/\"");

            return new CustomString(sb.ToString());
        }
```

But due to the Uri being called like below in the JavaScriptSerializer class:

```
private static void SerializeUri(Uri uri, StringBuilder sb)
{
  sb.Append("\"").Append(uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SerializationInfoString, UriFormat.UriEscaped)).Append("\"");
}
```

I get an escaped string of **"\"%22%5C/Date(1431010958974)%5C/%22\""** instead of **\"\/Date(1431006511857)\/\"**

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: I've changed the way I build the string to :   
                sb.Append("/Date(");
                var dtVal = ...
                sb.Append(dtVal);
                sb.Append(")/"); Which seems to give the result I want will test a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Data Contract Surrogates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will allow you to replace you DateTimeEx with an actual DateTime during serialization. I use this to replace my capital (Pascal case) property name that I like in C# with lower (camel) case names for use in JavaScript.

Its really just an interface ([IDataContractSurrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate(v=vs.110).aspx)) where you would probably only implement a couple methods. This gets passed into your serializer's constructor. Or, in WCF, it can be added as an operation behavior (example in the link).

I can't be sure if this would suit your particular situation without further details though.